# Deploy Vue frontend and node backend docker image with nginx

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, nginx, deployment

I have a Vue frontend and a separate Node backend. I want to deploy the whole thing and have created a docker image for the frontend and a docker image for the backend. Unfortunately the data from the backend is not visible on my frontend. My backend is running on port 3000.

The nginx.conf of the frontend looks like this:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # port that Express serves
}
location / {
  root   /app;
  index  index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
  }
}
```

In Webstorm everything works but as soon as I build the docker images it doesn't work, respectively I don't see the data from the backend in my frontend.

What have I forgotten to consider? And how should the config files in my backend looks like that it works?

Thanks for help!
Regards.

Comment: are you able to access the api from browser ?

Comment: Do you mean http://localhost:8080/api? If I enter this in my browser I get a Error message. (An error occurred. Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Please try again later.

Comment: There is no service at `http://localhost:3000` inside frontend docker.. Use nginx config on host machine (outside) or link api container with frontend docker(f.e. docker-compose link) and then use `http://api-container-name:3000`.

Comment: How can I link api container with frontend docker via http://api-container-name:3000? Where do I have to note this? In the ngnix.conf file of my frontend oder in a conf file in my backend?

Comment: It's docker thing. Either as argument in docker start command or more elegant way with docker-compose yaml file..